# Simulating a Home Button Press - iPhone Testing

Tags: iphone, automated-tests, uianimation

So I'm working on testing an iPhone app. I'm trying to setup test cases that we can use later using UIAutomation (I'm not really tied down to this - I can switch to some other framework). I basically need to create a test that goes something like:

```
+ Launches application
+ Clicks a few specific buttons
+ Hits the home button exiting the application
+ Relaunches the application
+ Checks the status of the application
```

Does anyone have any idea how to do this or what framework to use to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't simulate the home button being pressed, but you can force the app to exit as if it were. Calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminate];` will terminate or (in the case of iOS 4.x) background the app. You will not, however, be able to relaunch the application using UIAutomation.

You could try UIAutomation in combination with a screen recording script that allows you to replay mouse movement and clicks. This would allow you to interact with the simulator directly for things like home button clicks and app icon clicks.

Alternately you can get "good enough" testing using the [`UIATarget` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html). Per the docs,

> The **UIATarget** class represents high-level user interface elements of
>   the system under test (SUT)—that is, your application, the iOS, and
>   the connected device on which they’re running. Your test scripts,
>   written in JavaScript and running in conjunction with the UI
>   Automation instrument, use this class and related UIA classes to
>   exercise the SUT and log results.

Using `UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(seconds);` you can background your app for n seconds.

> Use this method to test shifting your application to and from the
>   background execution context. Note that applications built using iOS
>   SDK 4.0 or later and running in iOS 4.0 and later aren’t necessarily
>   terminated when the user presses the Home button. See iOS Application
>   Programming Guide for details of multitasking and background execution
>   context.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to press the home button in Xcode 7 with UI Testing.

```
XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().pressButton(XCUIDeviceButton.Home)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33087217/142358

Comment: This is the way to do it for Swift users. Nice one @Steve!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible but you could use

```
UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(100);
```

To put your app in the background for a specific amount time.

Answer (score 0):

presses device home button in iOS

```
def hit_home
  home =`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "iOS Simulator"' -e'keystroke "H" using command down' -e'delay 2' -e'end tell'`
  puts("home button exits - #{home.to_i}")
end
```