# Simulating pressing the Home button in Xcode 7 UI Automation

Tags: swift, ios9, ui-automation, xcode7, ios-ui-automation

I've got it down to:

```
XCUIDevice.pressButton(noideawhatgoeshere)
```

I've tried XCUIDeviceButtonHome, home, Home, 1

How do I simulate pressing the home button in Xcode on iOS?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to get the device instance first. So to simulate pressing the home button:

```
XCUIDevice.sharedDevice().pressButton(XCUIDeviceButton.Home)
```

should work (it does for me on a physical device)

Thanks!

Mazen

**Swift 5 Version:**

```
XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
```

Also, verified it works in the simulator, at least in Xcode 11.2.1 on a simulated "iPad Pro (9.7-inch)" running iPadOS 13.2.2.

Comment: Anyone know of a way to double-press the home button to be able to task-kill the app between tests?

Comment: Swift 3: `XCUIDevice.shared().press(.home)`

Comment: Does something needs to be imported in order to use XCUIDevice (tried to import XCUIDevice)? I'm getting 'Cannot find 'XCUIDevice' in scope'.

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 4**:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.press(.home)
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift version **4.0.2** and **4.0.3**:

```
XCUIDevice.shared().press(XCUIDeviceButton.home)
```

Answer (score 2):

Objective C

```
    [XCUIDevice.sharedDevice pressButton: XCUIDeviceButtonHome];
```

There are also `XCUIDeviceButtonVolumeUp` for volume up button and `XCUIDeviceButtonVolumeDown` for volume down button.

Answer (score 1):

Now in Swift **4.1**:

```
XCUIDevice.shared.press(XCUIDevice.Button.home)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know of no way to simulate the home button - this might not be possible. You can sorta brute force it with: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminate];`  or you can put your app in the background for a specified duration with: `UIATarget.localTarget().deactivateAppForDuration(seconds);`

(excuses for using objc)